# Mandatory reification when using the 'mod' operator together with 'or'?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have written a CSP program using CLP(FD) and SWI-Prolog.

I think I need to improve my constraints' writing when I use the `mod` operator
together with `#\/` in my predicates.

A short example :

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

constr(X,Y,Z) :-
   X in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
   Y in {3,5,7},
   Z in {1,2},
   ((X #= 3)) #==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)),
   ((Z #= 1)) #<==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)).
```

If I call `constr(3,Y,Z).`, I get `Z #= 1`or `Z #= 2`.
This is because some intermediate variables (relative to the `mod` expressions) still need to be evaluated.

Of course the ideal would be to only obtain `Z #= 1`.

How could this be done ?

I know that if I write instead

```
((X #= 3)) #==> ((Z #= 1)),
((Z #= 1)) #<==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)).
```

everything works as expected.

But is this reification mandatory ? I mean, do I have to create a reification variable each time I have this pattern in my constraints :

```
(A mod n1 #= 0) #\/ (B mod n2 #= 0) #\/ ... #\/ (Z mod n26 #= 0)
```

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a very good observation and question! First, please note that this is in no way specific to `mod/2`. For example:

```
?- B #<==> X #= Y+Z, X #= Y+Z.
B in 0..1,
X#=_G1122#<==>B,
Y+Z#=X,
Y+Z#=_G1122.
```

In contrast, if we write this declaratively equivalently as:

```
?- B #<==> X #= A, A #= Y + Z, X #= A.
```

then we get exactly as expected:

```
A = X,
B = 1,
Y+Z#=X.
```

What is going on here? In all systems I am aware of, reification in general uses a **decomposition** of CLP(FD) expressions which unfortunately removes important information that is not recovered later. In the first example, it is *not* detected that the constraint `X #= Y+Z` is **entailed**, i.e., *necessarily holds*.

On the other hand, entailment of a single equality with non-composite arguments is correctly detected, as in the second example.

So yes, in general, you will need to rewrite your constraints in this way to enable optimal detection of entailment.

The lurking question is of course whether the CLP(FD) system could help you to detect such cases and perform the rewriting *automatically*. Also in this case, the answer is *yes*, at least for certain cases. However, the CLP(FD) system typically is told only individual constraints in a certain sequence, and recreating and analyzing a global overview of all posted constraints in order to merge or combine previously decomposed constraints is typically not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mat, for this deep explanation. How could I make the CLP(FD) system help me detect such cases and perform the rewriting automatically ? My idea was to write : `((X #= 3)) #==> T,
((Z #= 1)) #<==> T,
T #<==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)).`

Comment: It would be easy to add particular special cases to the CLP(FD) system, but this is not sufficient: For example, in your case we also would need to modify `(#=)/2` (which uses a similar decomposition for arithmetic expressions) to detect at runtime (or compile time) whether one of the special cases is now applicable, *and then* rewrite the constraints dynamically. I consider the overhead of this too high: It is better that you rewrite the expressions yourself in this way, which should be quite easy. You can open a new question to discuss how we can rewrite such expressions within your program!

Comment: Ok, thanks again. I will try to make this rewriting by myself.

Answer (score 3):

With the (semi-official) `contracting/1` predicate, you can minimize some domains in one fell swoop.  In your case:

```
| ?- constr(3,Y,Z).
clpz:(Z#=1#<==>_A),
clpz:(_B#=0#<==>_C),
clpz:(_D#=0#<==>_E),
clpz:(_F#=0#<==>_G),
clpz:(_H#=0#<==>_I),
clpz:(_C#\/_E#<==>1),
clpz:(_G#\/_I#<==>_A),
clpz:(Y mod 3#=_B),
clpz:(Y mod 3#=_F),
clpz:(Y mod 7#=_D),
clpz:(Y mod 7#=_H),
clpz:(Y in 3\/5\/7),
clpz:(Z in 1..2),
clpz:(_C in 0..1),
clpz:(_B in 0..2),
clpz:(_E in 0..1),
clpz:(_D in 0..6),
clpz:(_A in 0..1),
clpz:(_G in 0..1),
clpz:(_F in 0..2),
clpz:(_I in 0..1),
clpz:(_H in 0..6) ? ;
no
```

And now by adding a single goal:

```
| ?- constr(3,Y,Z), clpz:contracting([Z]).
Z = 1,
clpz:(_A#=0#<==>_B),
clpz:(_C#=0#<==>_D),
clpz:(_E#=0#<==>_F),
clpz:(_G#=0#<==>_H),
clpz:(_B#\/_D#<==>1),
clpz:(_F#\/_H#<==>1),
clpz:(Y mod 3#=_A),
clpz:(Y mod 3#=_E),
clpz:(Y mod 7#=_C),
clpz:(Y mod 7#=_G),
clpz:(Y in 3\/5\/7),
clpz:(_B in 0..1),
clpz:(_A in 0..2),
clpz:(_D in 0..1),
clpz:(_C in 0..6),
clpz:(_F in 0..1),
clpz:(_E in 0..2),
clpz:(_H in 0..1),
clpz:(_G in 0..6) ? ;
no
```

In other words, a more consistent version of your predicate `constr/3` would be:

```
constr_better(X, Y, Z) :-
   constr(X, Y, Z),
   clpz:contracting([Z]).
```

Above I used SICStus with `library(clpz)` which is the successor to `library(clpfd)` of SWI which has `clpfd:contracting/1`, too.

Comment: `constr/3` is your definition, verbatim, no extra improvements. And then I used the predefined `contracting/1`.

Comment: So do I have to right this : `res(X,L) :- contracting(X), setof(X, indomain(X), L).` ?

Comment: Why do you want to use this `setof/3` at all? Seems you are interested in getting better bounds. And contracting/1 does this for you.

Comment: I get my resulting domains in "out" variables Xout, Yout, Zout. So my labelling predicates were : `res(X,L) :- setof(X, indomain(X), L).

constrChoice(X,Y,Z,XOut,YOut,ZOut) :-
constr(X,Y,Z),
res(X,XOut),res(Y,YOut),res(Z,ZOut).` I just need to adapt this to add `contracting/1`, but where ?

Comment: You add `contracting/1` like above!

Comment: `res(X,L) :- setof(X, indomain(X), L).

constrChoice(X,Y,Z,XOut,YOut,ZOut) :-
constr(X,Y,Z), clpfd:contracting([X]), clpfd:contracting([Y]), clpfd:contracting([Z]),
res(X,XOut),res(Y,YOut),res(Z,ZOut).` seems to be working :)

Comment: Or simpler `res(X,L) :- clpfd:contracting([X]), setof(X, indomain(X), L).

constrChoice(X,Y,Z,XOut,YOut,ZOut) :-
constr(X,Y,Z), res(X,XOut),res(Y,YOut),res(Z,ZOut).`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious help. The use of `contracting/1` on all my variables (86) doesn't cost more time, a relief.

Comment: I just noticed that the use of `contracting/1` does nothing when you have `#/\ ` instead of `#\/ ` : `constr(X,Y,Z) :-
   X in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
   Y in {3,5,7},
   Z in {1,2},
   ((X #= 3)) #==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #/\ (Y mod 7 #= 0)),
   ((Z #= 1)) #<==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #/\ (Y mod 7 #= 0)).` Calling `constr(3,Y,Z), clpfd:contracting([Y,Z]).` gives `Z in 1..2.`

Comment: You last definition fails for `constr(3,Y,Z)` - without any need for `contracting`

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things, I ended up with these conclusions, tell me if I am wrong (sorry, I am a beginner).

Let's consider this sample :

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

constr(X,Y,Z) :-
   X in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
   Y in {3,5,7,21,42},
   Z in {1,2},
   (X #= 3) #==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)),
   (Z #= 1) #<==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)).

constr_better(X,Y,Z) :- constr(X,Y,Z), clpfd:contracting([X,Y,Z]).

res(X,L) :- setof(X, indomain(X), L).

constrChoice(X,Y,Z,XOut,YOut,ZOut) :-
   constr(X,Y,Z),
   res(X,XOut),res(Y,YOut),res(Z,ZOut).

constrChoiceBetter(X,Y,Z,XOut,YOut,ZOut) :-
   constr_better(X,Y,Z),
   res(X,XOut),res(Y,YOut),res(Z,ZOut).
```

1. `constr(3,Y,Z)` gives `Z in 1..2` **but** `constrChoice(3,Y,Z,Xout,Yout,Zout)` gives `Zout=[1]` , so no need to use `contracting/1` because the use of `setof/3` together with `indomain/1` does the job. No need to rewrite prolog predicates either.
2. Now if I have AND `#/\` instead of OR `#\/`, none of the calls `constr(3,Y,Z)`,`constrChoice(3,Y,Z,Xout,Yout,Zout)` or `constrChoiceBetter(3,Y,Z,Xout,Yout,Zout)` gives that Z must be 1. I effectively     have that Y is 21 or 42, but Z is told to be 1 or 2.
   What works : write that `Y mod 21 #= 0` directly, and then no need to use `contracting/1` either.

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Sorry about that... What is difficult to understand ?

Comment: In 2 your are describing indirectly how the code looks like, but that is impossible to reproduce.

Comment: What is impossible to reproduce ? I don't see what you mean. In my code sample replace #\/ with #/\ then call the queries in 2, you will see that Z is not said to be 1.

Comment: No idea how the *very precise* code looks like in 2. I already showed you that this fails!

Comment: You need to put minimal and complete examples out!

Comment: It's not the same example as above, I added 21 and 42 into Y's domain value, so it doesn't fail. You obtain X = 3, Y in 21 \/ 42, Z in 1..2