# How to dynamically rewrite CLP(FD) constraints to help reification

Tags: prolog, clpfd, reification

My question is linked to this (now 1-year-old) post regarding reification issues in a CLP(FD) program : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417658/mandatory-reification-when-using-the-mod-operator-together-with-or)

The prolog file I give to the SWI engine is programmatically written on-the-fly, based on some data that users can add/edit/remove with another application (the same that calls the engine afterwards).

I want to detect some special cases to dynamically rewrite constraints to help the "engine" find the smallest possible domains.
An example :

```
 constr(X,Y,Z) :-
   X in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
   Y in {3,5,7},
   Z in {1,2},
   ((X #= 3)) #==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)),
   ((Z #= 1)) #<==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)).
```

If I call `constr(3,Y,Z).`, I get `Z #= 1` or `Z #= 2`.

One solution is to automatically replace the last two lines by

```
((X #= 3)) #==> T, 
((Z #= 1)) #<==> T, 
T #<==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)).
```

With this one I get `Z #= 1.`

The trouble is I can have this :

```
   ((X #= 3)) #==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)),
   ((Z #= 1)) #<==> ((Y mod 7 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 3 #= 0)).
```

How to detect this ? Can the Prolog engine help me to do this ? 
I thought I could programmatically replace each right operand by a reification variable :

```
   ((X #= 3)) #==> J,
   ((Z #= 1)) #<==> K,
   J #<==> ((Y mod 3 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 7 #= 0)),
   K #<==> ((Y mod 7 #= 0) #\/ (Y mod 3 #= 0)).
```

But in that case the same "reification" problem occurs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "... If I call `constr(3,Y,Z).`, I get `Z #= 1` or `Z #= 2`." No you don't get that! You get `Z in 1..2` plus a bunch of additional constraints!

Comment: You are right, this is what I get : `[...]
Z#=1#<==>_G1622,
Z in 1..2,
_G1562 in 0..6,
_G1562#=0#<==>_G1718,
_G1718 in 0..1,
_G1744#\/_G1718#<==>1,
_G1744 in 0..1,
_G1574#=0#<==>_G1744,
_G1574 in 0..2.` So how to use the bunch of additional constraints to deduce that Z must be equal to 1 ? I use the following labelling predicate : `res(X,L) :- setof(X, indomain(X), L). constrChoice(X,Y,Z,XOut,YOut,ZOut) :-
constr(X,Y,Z),
res(X,XOut),res(Y,YOut),res(Z,ZOut).`

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41591620/772868)?

Comment: Yes, right now, but I didn't catch what you tried to explain...